# cannot use v-for on stateful component root element in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to build small application on `Vuejs 2.0` where I'm having component file named `Text.Vue` and following are the components:

```
<template>
    <!-- Post -->
    <div class="blog-item" v-for="item in items">

        <!-- Post Title -->
        <h2 class="blog-item-title font-alt"><a href="#">{{ item.title }}</a></h2>

        <!-- Author, Categories, Comments -->
        <div class="blog-item-data">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ item.created_at }} </a>
            <span class="separator">&nbsp;</span>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> John Doe</a>
            <span class="separator">&nbsp;</span>
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
            <a href="">Design</a>, <a href="#">Branding</a>
            <span class="separator">&nbsp;</span>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 5 Comments</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Text Intro -->
        <div class="blog-item-body">
            <p>
                {{ item.content }}
            </p>
        </div>

        <!-- Read More Link -->
        <div class="blog-item-foot">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-mod btn-round  btn-small">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End Post -->
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                title: 'POST WITH TEXT ONLY',
                contents: 'Suspendisse accumsan interdum tellus, eu imperdiet lacus consectetur sed. Aliquam in ligula ac lacus blandit commodo vel luctus quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras eu ultrices mauris.',
                date_time: '4 December',
                items: []
            }
        },
        beforeCreate() {
            axios.get('/Blog/api/posts').then(response => {
                if(response.status === 200)
                {
                    this.items = response.data.posts
                }
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

While doing `npm run dev` or compiling the asset file I'm getting and error:

> - Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements.

I don't know where I'm doing mistake, help me out in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When creating a component there needs to be `1` root element, try wrapping your code in a `<div/>` tag. It should solve the issue;

i.e.

```
<div>
    <div class="blog-item" v-for="item in items">
        // Your code...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Because vue2.0 use latest grammar is to do。
for example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="blog-item" v-for="item in items">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```